# Gibbs Sampler, Bivariate Normal, Subchain

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, conditional-expectation, gibbs, multivariate-normal-distribution

In Example 7.1 of ["Introducing Monte Carlo Methods with R"](http://amzn.to/2kSOnNa), the authors write

$(X,Y)\sim N\Bigg((0,0),\begin{pmatrix}1 &\rho \\ \rho & 1\end{pmatrix}\Bigg)$

Then,

1. Given $x_t$,
2. $Y_{t+1}\mid x_t \sim N(\rho x_t, 1-\rho^2)$
3. $X_{t+1}\mid y_{t+1} \sim N(\rho y_{t+1}, 1-\rho^2)$

Finally, they say: The subchain $(X_t)_t$ satisfies 
$$ X_{t+1} \mid X_t = x_t\sim N(\rho ^2 x_t,1-\rho^4) $$.

I'm at a loss for how to show this.  I did

$$
\begin{align}
f(x_{t+1}\mid x_{t}) &= \int_\mathbb{R} f(x_{t+1}, y_{t+1} \mid x_t)dy_{t+1}\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi(1-\rho^2)}\int_{\mathbb{R}}exp\Big[ \frac{-1}{2(1-\rho^2)}\big((y_{t+1} - \rho x_t)^2+ (x_{t+1}-\rho y_{t+1})^2\big) \Big] dy_{t+1}
\end{align}
$$
where I have assumed  $X_{t+1}$ is conditionally independent of $X_t$ given $Y_{t+1}$.

But I just don't know where to go from there.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry if this is unclear in [our book](http://amzn.to/2kSOnNa), but when
\begin{align*}
Y_{t+1}\mid X_t=x_t &\sim \mathrm{N}(\rho x_t, 1-\rho^2)\\
X_{t+1}\mid Y_{t-1}=y_{t+1},X_t=x_t &\sim \mathrm{N}(\rho y_{t+1}, 1-\rho^2)
\end{align*}
one gets
$$X_{t+1}|X_t=x_t \sim \mathrm{N}(\rho \times \rho x_t,1-\rho^2+\rho^2(1-\rho^2))$$
as
$$\mathbb{E}[X_{t+1}|X_t]=\underbrace{\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X_{t+1}|Y_{t+1}]|X_t]}_{\mathbb{E}[\rho Y_{t+1}|X_t]=\rho^2 X_t}$$
and
$$\text{var}(X_{t+1}|X_t)=\underbrace{\mathbb{E}[\text{var}(X_{t+1}|Y_{t+1})|X_t)}_{\mathbb{E}[1-\rho^2|X_t]=1-\rho^2}+\underbrace{\text{var}(\mathbb{E}[X_{t+1}|Y_{t+1}]|X_t)}_{\rho^2\text{var}(Y_{t+1}|X_t)=\rho^2(1-\rho^2)}$$
If one wants to solve by the integral in the question,
\begin{align*}
&\exp\left\{\frac{-1}{2(1-\rho^2)}\big((y - \rho x_t)^2+ (x_{t+1}-\rho y)^2\big)\right\}\\
&\quad = \exp\left\{\frac{-1}{2(1-\rho^2)}\big(y^2(1+\rho^2)-2y(\rho x_t+\rho x_{t+1})+\rho^2 x_t^2+x_{t+1}^2\big)\right\}\\
&\quad = \exp\left\{\frac{-(1+\rho^2)}{2(1-\rho^2)}\big(y^2-2\rho (x_t+x_{t+1})y/(1+\rho^2)+\rho^2(x_t+x_{t+1})^2/(1+\rho^2)^2\big)\right\}\\
&\quad\times\exp\left\{\frac{-1}{2(1-\rho^2)}\big(\rho^2 x_t^2+x_{t+1}^2-\rho^2(x_t+x_{t+1})^2/(1+\rho^2)\big)\right\}\\
\end{align*}
which makes the first exponential term a perfect normal density in $y$ and the second term can be simplified into
\begin{align*}
&\exp\left\{\frac{-1}{2(1-\rho^2)}\big(\rho^2 x_t^2+x_{t+1}^2-\rho^2(x_t+x_{t+1})^2/(1+\rho^2)\big)\right\}\\
&\quad=\exp\left\{\frac{-1}{2(1-\rho^2)(1+\rho^2)}\big(
(1+\rho^2)[\rho^2 x_t^2+x_{t+1}^2]-\rho^2(x_t+x_{t+1})^2\big)\right\}\\
&\quad=\exp\left\{\frac{-1}{2(1-\rho^4}\big(
x_{t+1}^2[1+\rho^2-\rho^2]-2x_tx_{t+1} \rho^2+x_t^2\rho^2[1+\rho^2-\rho^2]\big)\right\}\\&\quad=\exp\left\{\frac{-1}{2(1-\rho^4)}\big(
x_{t+1}-\rho^2 x_t\big)^2\right\}\\\end{align*}
which leads to the same result (!)

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I understand the integration which shows the result is normally distributed with given mean and variance.  However, I have one follow-up question. In the first part, you used the laws of total expectation/variance to derive the mean and variance.  But that part alone does not guarantee normality (right?).  Is there a theorem we can appeal to which lets us conclude X_{t+1} | X_t is normal simply based on the setup? Such a theorem, paired with the laws of total exp/var, would constitute a slick and parsimonious derivation. Either way, thanks for completing the integration.

Comment: Indeed, I also used the fact that $(X_{t+1},Y_{t+1})$ given $X_t$ being normal implies that $X_{t+1}$ given $X_t$ is also normal.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this view helps:
\begin{align}
Y_{t + 1} &= \rho x_t + \sqrt{1 - \rho^2} N_t \\
X_{t + 1} 
&= \rho Y_{t + 1} + \sqrt{1 - \rho^2} N_{t + 1} \\
&= \rho^2 x_t + \rho \sqrt{1 - \rho^2} N_t + \sqrt{1 - \rho^2} N_{t + 1},
\end{align}
where $N_t$ and $N_{t + 1}$ are standard normal distributed. It is then easy to see that 
$$\mathbb{E}[X_{t + 1} | x_t] = \rho^2 x_t + 0 + 0$$
and
$$\mathbb{V}[X_{t + 1} \mid x_t] = \rho^2(1 - \rho^2) + (1 - \rho^2) = (1 + \rho^2)(1 - \rho^2) = 1 - \rho^4,$$
where we have used that [the variance of the sum is the sum of the variances for uncorrelated variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sum_of_uncorrelated_variables_.28Bienaym.C3.A9_formula.29) and the [third binomial formula](https://www.math.utah.edu/online/1010/binom/).

Comment: I am curious why this answer got downvoted?